# Form work on server, not locally. Ultimately need a programatic solution to submit the form

Tags: http, curl, asp-classic

I need to submit this form (preferrebly using cURL):

```
<form method="post" action="results.asp" name=FrontPage_Form1 onSubmit="return true">
<input name="regno" size="7" maxlength=7>
<input type="submit" name="B1" size="15" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This form is on a website and works well there, redirects to page http:website//results.asp and shows the information.

BUT if I download this html form and open it in my local browser and submit, it does not work

> the results.asp page says 'Access denied' in html page generated by the asp page.

Additional information:
    - when the html page is on the same server: entering a wrong 'regno' results in a page which says exactly that
    - Upon opening this form locally, it always says, access denied.

Please let me know if any of this is not clear.

Comment: Maybe it checks the `Referer`.

Comment: post the code of results.asp

Comment: The code in `results.asp` probably checks for a referer. You have to look in that file for your solution. If you post it here, or parts, we might be able to help you further.

Comment: thanks for the comments; but I do not have access to results.asp. Also I have put this project on hold for now....

Answer (score 0):

If you open an html file into your local browser and then try to post to another page without the full URL, then it will look in the same directory for that file, which I imagine doesn't exist since you don't have access to it. You need to enter the full path in the form action, like so:

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.resultsserver.com/results.asp" name=FrontPage_Form1 onSubmit="return true">
```